# Efficient retrieval of large data sets in Mongo mapper?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongomapper, large-data-volumes

I am storing a large amount of Twitter data, and would like to retrieve about 500k records for data processing at a time. I have a TwitterTweet mongo document that contains basic tweet data, and try to retrieve it as follows:

`weekly_tweets = TwitterTweet.all(:created_at.gt => 1.week.ago, :fields => [:created_at, :text, :from_user])`

Trouble is, this take up a LOT of time and memory - is there any way to make this more scalable and efficient. I have thought of using map reduce, but it looks very complicated for what I want to do - text processing and regexp stuff on the tweets.

Comment: why not more, smaller calls? Use skip and limit and take it 1000 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call all as this has the effect of making an object of all 500k of your entries in mongo and will as you noticed use a ton of memory and time.  Use find_each instead and iterate through.  Find returns a cursor which is way more efficient.

Comment: I can't seem to find the docs to describe this operation. Could you help me convert the .all() code in my question to a .find() iteration?

Comment: Well in the raw mongo driver you can just do find, but with mongomapper it appears that you have to do a where query coupled with find_each.  Or you can do skip(x) and then do a limit for batches of 10000 etc.  In general I do not like mongomapper as it is inconsistent and not good for large data. Check out that documentation even though they do not know what their code does due to documenting it after it is been out for a while.  You can do all skip and limit or where with find each.  Or you can just use 10gen mongo lib and just call find and it works better.